# Custom attribute for select option and accessing it from AbstractControl in Angular 5?

Tags: javascript, angular5

I would like to create a custom attribute for each option element in a select element, but I am having trouble creating one that can be accessed via AbstractControl and event.target. Here is what I have:

I tried making a custom attribute called code, then tried using the id.

```
<select id="country" formControlName="country" class="form-control" (change)="getStates($event.target.value, $event.target.id)">
    <option id = "{{cntry.code}}" *ngFor="let cntry of countries" [value]="cntry.id" [attr.code] = "cntry.code">{{cntry.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Elsewhere in the code, I have:

```
editForm.controls['country'].id
```

I had previously tried

```
editForm.controls['country'].code
```

but that didn't work either. I already have the value set for the option element so I can't use that. The attribute has to be accessible via AbstractControl and event.target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a property country to your TypeScript for the component

```
country: Country; // Whatever type your countries are
```

then use ngModel to bind to the country and use ngValue for the options and bind to the country objects

```
<select id="country" formControlName="country" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="country" (change)="getStates()">
    <option *ngFor="let cntry of countries" [ngValue]="cntry">{{cntry.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Then in your getStates method you can use the property on the componenet with this.country

If you get a no ngModel property on select error then you need to add the Angular forms module to your module.